# no mapping for the unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page - Datasnap / JSON / ISSO

Tags: android, delphi, iis, rad-studio

I have an application written in Delphi 10.4.1 using DataSnap on Android and ISAPI (IIS).

When I try to send an image by `TStream` (or `TMemoryStream`, or even with `TJSONDataSets`), I always receive an error:

> no mapping for the unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page

It happens before the invoke of my server-class.

My code:

```pascal
var
  vMS: TMemoryStream;
  vSS: TStringStream;
  vJson: TJsonObject;
  vServer: TClientesClient;
begin
  vMS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  vSS := TStringStream.Create;
    
  try
    if not DMDataRest.FVBancoConn.Connected then
      DMDataRest.FVBancoConn.Connected := True;
    
    dmDataRest.QAUX.Close;
    dmDataRest.QAUX.SQL.Clear;
    dmDataRest.QAUX.SQL.Add('Select *');
    dmDataRest.QAUX.SQL.Add('from clientesImagens');
    dmDataRest.QAUX.Open();
    
    while not dmDataRest.QAUX.Eof do
    begin
      vMS := TMemoryStream(dmDataRest.QAUX.CreateBlobStream(dmDataRest.QAUX.FieldByName('ci_Imagem'), TBlobStreamMode.bmRead));
      vMS.Position := 0;
    
      TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(vMS, vSS);
      vSS.Position := 0;
    
      vJson := TJsonObject.Create;
      vJson.AddPair('boleto1', vSS.DataString);
    
      vServer := TClientesClient.Create(dmDataRest.RESTConnect);
      vServer.setImagemClienteJson(vJson, 2);
    
      dmDataRest.QAUX.Next;
    end;
    
  finally
    dmDataRest.QAUX.Close;
    DMDataRest.FVBancoConn.Connected := False;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Not related to your error, but you are leaking 3 `TStream` objects. You need to fix that. You shouldn't be creating 3 `TStream` objects, only 2. Get rid of `vMS := TMemoryStream.Create;` altogether, and change `vMS := TMemoryStream(...CreateBlobStream(...));` to just `vMS := ...CreateBlobStream(...);` (and change the declaration of `vMS` to `TStream`). Then you just need to add `vMS.Free` and `vSS.Free` inside the loop when you are done using those streams. You also have a *potential* leak of `vJson` too, depending on whether `TClientesClient.setImagemClienteJson()` takes ownership or not

Comment: i know about those leek. I just put some part of the code to simulate the error. Anyway, tkx